# Swift:How to make SegmentedControl notice value change done by swiping?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uisegmentedcontrol

I have segmented control inside the UITableViewCell custom class. I added swipe gesture to enable modifying the value also by swipe. Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
In awakeFromNib() method in  I add this line:

```
segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentValueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

to observe changes to the value of segmented control.
Here is the implementation of mentioned method

```
    func segmentValueChanged(sender: AnyObject){

    if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 0 {

        segmentControl.thumbColor = UIColor(red: 231.0/255.0, green: 76.0/255.0, blue: 60.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        segmentControl.selectedLabelColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        segmentControl.unselectedLabelColor = UIColor.grayColor()


    }else if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 1{

        segmentControl.thumbColor = UIColor(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 113.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        segmentControl.selectedLabelColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        segmentControl.unselectedLabelColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    }
```

Here is my function that handles swipes

```
 func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)

    {
        if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 1 && sender.direction == .Left

        {

            self.segmentControl.selectedIndex = 0

        }

        if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 0 && sender.direction == .Right

        {

            self.segmentControl.selectedIndex = 1

        }

    }
```

The problem is: When I swipe segmentValueChanged does not notice any change is selectedIndex value? 
I tried playing around with target and senders, but without any good result unfortunately

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I add gesture inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: cell, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

```
    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: cell, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

 leftSwipe.direction = .Left

 rightSwipe.direction = .Right

 cell.segmentControl.thumbView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

 cell.segmentControl.thumbView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
```

EDIT: 
In custom segment control I found this method, maybe editing it could solve the issue, but I do not have idea how to do that

```
override func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

    let location = touch.locationInView(self)

    var calculatedIndex : Int?
    for (index, item) in labels.enumerate() {
        if item.frame.contains(location) {
            calculatedIndex = index
        }
    }


    if calculatedIndex != nil {
        selectedIndex = calculatedIndex!
        sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Did you add gesture recogniser to your view? to make sure try putting a breakpoint and see if its getting a hit

Comment: Yes I did, the gesture generally works, it moves the segment control but do not overwrite the value

Comment: I updated the question to allow you to see the implementation

Comment: Do you want to trigger the event value changed when you swipe?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)

    {
        if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 1 && sender.direction == .Left

        {

            self.segmentControl.selectedIndex = 0

            segmentControl.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)

        }

        if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 0 && sender.direction == .Right

        {

            self.segmentControl.selectedIndex = 1
            segmentControl.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)

        }

    }
```

> segmentControl.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)

solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot trigger segmented control value changed by changing the selected index

You can call your

*segmentValueChanged(segmentedControl)*

at the end of

*handleswipes()*

Updated the code in [sampleTableReuse](https://github.com/vinbhai4u/sampletablereuse)

Please use this only for inspiration and try to modify your code accordingly

Comment: This way the value is not observed in tableView and also it's not memorized

Comment: @DCDC you can get the segmented control from the sender of the gesture swipe

Comment: Actually I see that segmentValueChanged spots the change of value but it's not visible for tableView

Comment: this is the same commit as you showed me before, there are no swipes implemented

Comment: Sorry I forgot to sync my bad :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it later on and get back to you!:)

Comment: This does not work for me because let a = sender.view as! QuestionYesNoCustomCellTableViewCell is not able to cast sender.view to cell. Remember that I add my gesture to the thumb view, so how can I obtain cell out of that?

Comment: @DCDC are you calling the swipe gesture inside tableviewcell cellforindex?

Comment: Yeah I did. I've edited the question, maybe now it would be easier to solve it

Comment: I did, see my answer above

Comment: @DCDC Good, happy to hear. Please accept the most helpful answer :)